# How to tell if webpage is running in chrome application shortcut mode

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

We can create application shortcut in google Chrome.
I would like to display a different layout when my web page is running in application shortcut mode - which basically is running in a separate standalone window.

Is there a way to tell if web page is running in application shortcut mode?

Right now I am testing if the window can be re-sized by JavaScript - assuming that it is running in application shortcut mode if the window can be re-sized.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

[Update]
Basically we want to know if the webpage is running in a single window or running in one tab of a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just googled a bit and found this site: http://blog.kenneth.io/blog/2010/05/04/desktop-icons-in-google-chrome/

You can see this `<meta>` element in the first code block:

```
<meta name="application-url" content="http://www.example.com"/>
```

I haven't found any reliable and offcial documentation* yet, but it seems to work in a quick test I've just made.

In that way, you could pass an extra query string to your URI which only gets called when opening from a pinned (taskbar|desktop) short cut.

*) <sub>This <meta> element is also unofficially metioned here: [Page Meta Properties - mozilla f1](https://github.com/mozilla/f1/wiki/Page-Meta-Properties).</sub>

---

### How can it be used?

- Create a new HTML document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="application-url" content="http://www.exaple.com?shortcut=true" />

    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    Test
  </body>
</html>
```

- Now, open this document in Google chrome (works also with local file system!).
- Create a taskbar and/or desktop shortcut via Chrome's *Tools* menu.
- Chrome will open another window with the original URI. This is possibly a bug.

  But if you use the shortcut, Chrome will open the URI provided in the *<meta>* tag (here: `http://www.exaple.com?shortcut=true`).

Comment: I'm sorry but could you tell me more clearly how does the meta tag help for my case? How do I define the meta in my html and what's the difference when it's running from shortcut?

Comment: You are right! When running from shortcut, it's openning the URL from the meta tag. Thanks a lot!